# Use onTapUp event with Inkwell

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to run code on the onTapUp event in the inkwell widget, like I can on a GestureDetector? onTapUp event isn't available between the parameters while onTapDown and onTapCancel etc are, is it a bug? Is there some way I could use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InkWell` doesn't have a `onTapUp` property. You can wrap `InkWell` with `GestureDetector`:

```dart
GestureDetector(
    onTapUp: () => youFunction(), // your function goes here
    child: InkWell(...),
);
```

Comment: `InkWell` now has the `onTapUp` property https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html#onTapUp

Answer (score 0):

make custom class

for example

```
class CustomInkWell extends StatelessWidget{
  var onTabUp;
  CustomInkWell({this.onTabUp});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapUp: onTabUp,
      child: InkWell(
        //your code
      ),
    );
  }
}
```